# TypeError when using numpy.take

Tags: python, numpy

I’m trying to use `numpy.take()` to get, like the documentation says, elements from an array along an axis.

**My code:**

```
print np.take(testArray,axis=1)
```

Gives the following counter-intuitive error:

```
TypeError: take() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

Well, if two are given, what is wrong then?

In order to debug, I printed the shapes:

```
print testArray[:, 1].shape
print testArray[:, 1]       

(1L, 4L)
[[      251       100         4 886271884]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a horrible error message, and fortunately it's fixed in Python 3.3 and up.

What it actually means is that the function takes at least two *postional* arguments, but you have given one positional argument and one keyword argument.  You also need to provide an array of indices as second argument to specify which elements to take; see the [documentation of `numpy.take()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) for further details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As Sven has mentioned, you're only supplying 1 of the required arguments. The `axis` argument is only optional. The 2nd argument you need is a python list of indices of elements you want to extract:

```
print(np.take(testArray, list(range(testArray.shape[1])), axis=1))
```

And if you're using python < 3.0, where range() still returned a list:

```
print np.take(testArray, range(testArray.shape[1]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation & the code!